# Issues with graphl query fragment into component (Gatsby+DatoCMS)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to pass down data from DatoCMS via graphql from my main page to a component using a fragment, however, I keep getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'datoCmsHome' of undefined` and when I navigate on GraphiQL it says the fragment is not being used anywhere.

page/index.js

```
export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    datoCmsHome {
      ...Slider_carouselImages
      introductionbody
      ourvaluesbody
      ourphilosophybody
      insuranceproviderslogos {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
`
```

component carousel.js

```
const SimpleSlider = ({ data }) => ({
  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>
          {data.datoCmsHome.carouselimages.map(({ id, url }) =>
            <div key={id}>
              <img src={url} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </Slider>
      );
    }
  }
);

export default SimpleSlider

export const query = graphql`
  fragment Slider_carouselImages on DatoCmsHome {
    carouselimages {
      id
      url
    }
  }
`
```

I'm a bit lost to understand what I'm I missing so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that using `<SimpleSlider data={data} />` on index.js was enough to get the data to the component, without the need for any graphql fragment.